# Android) Application Signature of weChat developers. What value do I put in it?

Tags: android, authentication, signature, wechat

I want to get the wechat login data.
Due to the problems of Application Signature, I had once failed.
Please tell me how to put a value on what 'Application Signature'.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check out this example code I found on github.](https://github.com/aaronbruckner/wechatAndroidLoginDemo)

> For the signature, use the MD5 hash of the key used to sign your
>   published APK. The easiest way to do this is to setup a signature to
>   always use for your debug/release builds. If you have a java keystore
>   holding a signing key within your project, you can add the following
>   to your app gradle file to sign your debug release with a constant
>   signature:
>
> ```
>  android {
>      ...
>      // Keystore located in root project folder. Google can show many examples on how to generate keystores with signatures
>
>      signingConfigs {
>          debug {
>              storeFile file('keystore.jks')
>              storePassword 'password'
>              keyAlias 'weChatDebug'
>              keyPassword 'password'
>          }
>      }
>      ... }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

An easier way would be to:

1. download this app by following this [link](https://github.com/mike623/cordova-WeChat-meteor-sharing/blob/master/README.md).
2. Install the app you want to generate the signature of (the app has to be signed)
3. Open the app you downloaded in step 1, fill in the name of the package of the app you installed in step 2 and click the button
4. A signature will be generated for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to put MD5 of your keystore. Keystore will be the one with whom you are signing your APK.